# BigDecimal - check value is within double range

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I have a Java application which parses a number from somewhere, and checks that it is a valid int (between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE) or a valid double (between Double.MIN_VALUE and Double.MAX_VALUE).

I'm using this code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

  public class Test  {

    public static final BigDecimal DOUBLE_MAX = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    public static final BigDecimal DOUBLE_MIN = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.MIN_VALUE);

    public static final BigInteger INTEGER_MIN = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    public static final BigInteger INTEGER_MAX = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    private static boolean inRange(BigDecimal value) {
        return DOUBLE_MAX.compareTo(value) >= 0 &&
          DOUBLE_MIN.compareTo(value) <= 0;
    }

    private static boolean inRange(BigInteger value) {
        return INTEGER_MAX.compareTo(value) >= 0 &&
          INTEGER_MIN.compareTo(value) <= 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(inRange(new BigInteger("1234656")));
        System.out.println(inRange(new BigInteger("0")));
        System.out.println(inRange(new BigInteger("-987")));

        System.out.println(inRange(new BigDecimal("1234656.0")));
        System.out.println(inRange(new BigDecimal("0.0")));
        System.out.println(inRange(new BigDecimal("-987.0")));
    }
  }
```

Which works fine for int values, but for some reason, fails for any zero or negative double value. So running the above produces the output:

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I've seen examples where DOUBLE_MIN is set to be -Double.MAX_VALUE. This works but is it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Double.MIN_VALUE` represents the minimum *positive* value. (That is, a positive value close to zero.)

From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html):

> *A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.*

This is the reason why

```
System.out.println(inRange(new BigDecimal("0.0")));
System.out.println(inRange(new BigDecimal("-987.0")));
```

outputs false. None of the provided values are (strictly) greater than 0.

### The solution

Since the range of `double`s are symmetrical around origo (as opposed to integers, which stretches one step further on the negative side) you can get the minimum (negative) value by writing `-Double.MAX_VALUE`. That is

```
BigDecimal DOUBLE_MIN = BigDecimal.valueOf(-Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thank you! guess I need to read the documentation a little more carefully.

Comment: Easy mistake to do, considering the meaning of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. The naming is indeed a bit missfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the javadoc for Double.MIN_VALUE it says

```
 A constant holding the smallest **positive nonzero** value of type
 <code>double</code>
```