# Doubles with constraints in Java?

Tags: java

I am porting a legacy Python system to Java. I'm a python developer primarily so this question concerns how I might take an unsatisfactory pattern in the original Python system but do it better in my Java version.

A system I'm working on deals with prices of products. All products have prices > 0.0.

In the orginal system all prices are represented as Python float objects (roughly like a Java Double). Functions which operate on these prices typically begin with a bunch of asserts to check that the range of the prices are sensible. Since there are a lot of functions there are a lot of assertions which become very repetitive after a while.

These assertions are better than nothing but it would be far better to throw an error the instant that something tried to create a negative price, since that's where the fault lies.

It occurred to me that I might do better in my re-implementation by inventing a new type of numberish thing which behaves exactly like a Double in all ways except that it cannot be constructed with a negative value. If I had such an object then I could rely on Java's type system and not need to write so many asserts.

Other than that (to begin with) it will obey all the normal rules of arethmatic - it will be a subclass of Double.

Later on I might extend this class by adding features that embrace more features of real-world money, e.g. preventing fractions of pennies. That's not actually needed in my initial version, but I'd like any pattern I adopt to accomodate this sort of development over the next few months.

Is this kind of pattern considered acceptable to a Java developer? Is there a better way to preserve the flexibility of having number-like objects but constraints on their possible values?

Comment: Well it is surely not a good idea to store prices in a `float` or `double` type fields. What you should always use is decimal type like `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: Have you considered using BigDecimal or BigInteger? Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411637/bigdecimal-check-value-is-within-double-range) question to see it it fits your needs.

Comment: Adding from gpeche: Double cannot be extended because it is final.

Comment: @ThorstenS. And thank you God for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, no real software that deals with money uses floating-point math, because of the imprecision. A "Money" class that holds integer numbers of pennies is one common way to deal with this.

Secondly, yes, having a constructor that rejects negative numbers by throwing an exception would be a fine thing to do for such a class.

[Here's](http://drdobbs.com/jvm/184405653?pgno=1) a good Dr. Dobb's Journal article on the topic, with code.

Comment: +1 A Money class maybe with an int for pennies/cents or a BigDecimal field is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable idea (except for using Double).  You can't extend Double since it's a final class.  Regardless, you should be using BigDecimal instead of Double (as @Jagger mentioned in the OP comments).  However, you're probably better off creating your own Price class and maintaining the BigDecimal internally since this will give you better control over how the value is used..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is indeed not only acceptable, but the very first thing a Java developer would do.
With one exception: *DO NOT USE FLOATS OR DOUBLES FOR MONETARY VALUES*!

I would suggest:

- That you create an interface with all the methods you would implement.
- Perhaps an abstract base class which is NOT a subclass of BigDecimal but uses a private value of BigDecimal (no subclassing, but delegation pattern)
- That you create the final class with implements all money functions, assertions and   safeguards.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, yes, subclassing **something** or writing a class for that would be acceptable and there are people who do it, you can't, however, subclass `java.lang.Double`, it's a `final` class. Throwing constructors are nowhere near the catastrophe they are in C++ or something.

Secondly, you shouldn't store it in `double` unless you really need fractions of pennies, which you just said you don't. An integer class would be a much better idea.

Thirdly, I'd suggest subclassing `java.lang.Number` to get all the benefits of autoboxing.

Comment: You cannot extend Double in java, it is `final`

Comment: @gpeche wtf are you talking about, where in my answer did I suggest subclassing `Double`?

Comment: @TC1: The original poster did wrote "it will be a subclass of Double" and you said, "subclassing would be acceptable". So gpeche was not totally unreasonable to assume that subclassing of double was meant when in fact you do not suggest it.